# Generate complete kotlintest report in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlintest

I am using [kotlintest](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest) with gradle. When I run my tests in IntelliJ I get to see the [whole Given/When/Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jC8T.png) structure. This is also reflected in the [report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afa7N.png) I can generate using the IntelliJ Export Test Results function. This works perfectly and does exactly what I want.

Sadly, when I run the tests using `gradlew test` it only picks up the Then blocks. That means that while all tests are run correctly, the generated report looks [ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMxDg.png).

The problem is that I want to generate an HTML report automatically in a Jenkins pipeline. At the moment the result is useless, because it does not contain the Given and When blocks.

Is it possible to somehow generate a complete HTML report, with all Given/When/Then blocks in a Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: The issue is that gradle itself doesn't support anything other than basic test layout. This is being addressed in gradle, and (hopefully) should be fixed soon (although it was 4.9 then 4.10 then ....). Perhaps kotlintest should offer its own HTML report option.